# Rename a label programmatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label

I am using visual studio 2008, using VB.NET.

I have a number of labels that I want to rename programmatically.

The current names for the labels take the form of label100, label101,label102 etc.

It sounds so simple but its got me beat, is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to rename the labels to?

Comment: Ah sorry I should have said. The names will take the form of 
player100 player101 player102 etc.

Comment: I would suggest a regex replace, but then you'd have two problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **label.Name** property to change the name of any label.

It doesn't rename the **declaration** of the variable, for that you'll need to use find/replace.

Example from MSDN help:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Connect the ControlRemoved and ControlAdded event handlers to the event-handler methods.
    ' ControlRemoved and ControlAdded are not available at design time.
    AddHandler Me.ControlRemoved, AddressOf Me.Control_Removed
    AddHandler Me.ControlAdded, AddressOf Me.Control_Added
End Sub 'Form1_Load


Private Sub Control_Added(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(("The control named " + e.Control.Name + " has been added to the form."))
End Sub


Private Sub Control_Removed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(("The control named " + e.Control.Name + " has been removed from the form."))
End Sub


' Click event handler for a Button control. Adds a TextBox to the form.
Private Sub addControl_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    ' Create a new TextBox control and add it to the form.
    Dim textBox1 As New TextBox()
    textBox1.Size = New Size(100, 10)
    textBox1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    ' Name the control in order to remove it later. 
    ' The name must be specified if a control is added at run time.
    textBox1.Name = "textBox1"

    ' Add the control to the form's control collection.
    Me.Controls.Add(textBox1)
End Sub


' Click event handler for a Button control.
' Removes the previously added TextBox from the form.
Private Sub removeControl_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button2.Click
    ' Loop through all controls in the form's control collection.
    Dim tempCtrl As Control
    For Each tempCtrl In Me.Controls
        ' Determine whether the control is textBox1,
        ' and if it is, remove it.
        If tempCtrl.Name = "textBox1" Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(tempCtrl)
        End If
    Next tempCtrl
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the label.Name property. I wonder if you would be kind enough to give an example of how I would use it. Thank you

Comment: Aye thats it exactly, I just want a bit of code, if its possible, that I can run once to change the names and then purge it from the app.

Comment: @Matthew & Simon: Yeah if you want to change the actual declaration of the variable, find/replace is your best bet there. Sorry if I added any confusion to the mix.

Answer (score 1):

The Find and Replace dialog would be your best bet.